# fetch binary file and get uin8Array data from it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, filereader

when i fetch binary file from aws server using code:

```
export const fetchBinaryFile = async(url: string): Promise<Uint8Array> => {
  try {
    const options: HttpOptions = {
      url,
      responseType: 'blob'
    };

    const response: HttpResponse = await CapacitorHttp.request(options);
    if (!response.data) {
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch binary file');
    }
    const blob = new Blob([response.data]);
    const arrayBuffer = await readBlobAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    return uint8Array;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
};

export const readBlobAsArrayBuffer = (blob: Blob): Promise<ArrayBuffer> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      if (reader.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
        console.log('resolve', reader.result);
        resolve(reader.result as ArrayBuffer);
      }
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  });
};
```

i can see that content-length is 27852 bytes. However, when i then procceed to transform to uin8Array, the byte length of uin8Array is waaaaay more. I can't understand why FileReader append meta tags(i guess). Uint8Array length becomes 37625 bytes....

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why have a `try-catch` block when you do _not_ catch errors but instead throw _a new error for every error you receive_?

Comment: @David, yeah i forgot to delete that. i was trying different way